# Comparing floats with more than 1 integer

Tags: r, floating-point

I would like to test whether the row sums of a matrix sum to 0 or 1.  The sums are floating point numbers, so direct comparisons with `==` do not work.

Here's an example:

```
# Sample matrix
mat <- matrix(rnorm(50), nrow = 5)

# Choose some row to sum to 1.  I will not know in advance which rows these are
sum.to.1 <- sample(1:5, 3)

mat.normalized <- mat

# Some rows sum to 1
mat.normalized[sum.to.1, ] <- mat[sum.to.1, ] / rowSums(mat[sum.to.1, ])

# Remaining rows sum to 0
mat.normalized[-sum.to.1, ] <- mat[-sum.to.1, ] - rowMeans(mat[-sum.to.1, ])

rowSums(mat.normalized)  # very close, but not exactly, 1 or 0

# I want something like this:
# all(rowSums(mat.normalized) %in% c(0, 1))
```

If I was just testing whether the rows summed to 1, or if I knew which rows would be 0 in advance, I would use `all.equal`.  But some rows will sum to 0, and I don't know *a priori* which rows those will be.

I also can't use `round` (I think), because all of the rows will round to 1 or 0 regardless of how close they are.

Any ideas?  Seems like there should be something simple for this, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: you can test if the absolute difference with 0/1 is less than a threshold

Comment: `round(rowSums(mat.normalized), floor(-log10(.Machine$double.eps)))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is likely a more eloquent answer, but you could use 2 passes of `sapply` with `all.equal` like this.

```
# get the sums
mySums <- rowSums(mat.normalized)

# run through values twice. Check for equal to 1, equal to 0, then sum the results
all(sapply(mySums, function(i) isTRUE(all.equal(i, 1))) +
    sapply(mySums, function(i) isTRUE(all.equal(i, 0))) == 1)
[1] TRUE
```

I added the `== 1` because the `+` will return a numerical vector and `all` complains about this. As hinted by @cath's comment, it is possible to avoid the `== 1` at the end. One such attempt is uses `Reduce`.

```
all(Reduce("|", sapply(mySums, function(i) isTRUE(all.equal(i, 1))),
                sapply(mySums, function(i) isTRUE(all.equal(i, 0)))))
```

or `mapply`

```
all(mapply("|", sapply(mySums, function(i) isTRUE(all.equal(i, 1))),
           sapply(mySums, function(i) isTRUE(all.equal(i, 0)))))
```

Comment: Good point, I'll add a second option. I add the `sapply` outputs together, resulting in a numeric vector. `all` will work on a numeric vector, but complains about it with a warning. For instance, try `all(1)`.

Comment: I went with @Roland's answer, in the comments above, but this is equally good, thanks.